# Multiple select with checkbox from dropdown in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, drop-down-menu, checkbox, primefaces

In PrimeFaces, can we choose multiple elements from drop down list with the help of checkbox? 
If my drop down is showing 5 elements, can I choose more than 1 element from the list?

I know in primeFaces we have `<p:selectOneMenu>` which will allow me to choose one element, but do we have something like `<p:selectMultipleMenu>`?

I was trying to find it out but not able to find something. Can you please let me know whether this is possible or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is `<p:selectCheckboxMenu />` and it seems to provide what you need as you can see in showcase on: [PrimeFacesShowCase-SelectCheckboxMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml)

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this only.

Comment: @miroslav_mijajlovic is there any thing like Multiple select with checkbox from dropdown in primeng angular2?

Comment: @ShaMoh take a look at https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect

Comment: @miroslav_mijajlovic groupBy multiple select with checkbox from dropdown in primeng angular2?

Comment: @miroslav_mijajlovic Is it possible to have GroupBy in MultiSelect Dropdown in primeng?

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the SelectManyMenu is exactly what you need.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyMenu.xhtml

EDIT: miroslav_mijajlovic's answer may be better because you wanted a drop down.

Comment: The component you referenced doesn't provide for a dropdown element, so your answer doesn't fit in.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @serenesat The essential part of the answer is the documentation for the manyMenu. I have updated the link to the new documentation. Aside from that, it actually didn't answer the original question since the original question was about a drop down menu, but I left my answer for posterity.